# How to use both `with_outputs` and `with_output_types` in Apache Beam (Python SDK)?

Tags: python, apache-beam

An Apache Beam `PTransform` can have `with_outputs` and `with_output_types` appended to it.  Eg,

```py
pcoll | beam.CombinePerKey(sum).with_output_types(typing.Tuple[unicode, int])
```

and

```py
(words | beam.ParDo(ProcessWords(), cutoff_length=2, marker='x')
             .with_outputs('above_cutoff_lengths', 'marked strings',
                           main='below_cutoff_strings')
)
```

(Both of these examples are taken from [Apache Beam documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/), if you want some context.)

But I cannot seem to find any documentation on how to *combine* them.  For instance, *can I do something like this*?

```py
(words | beam.ParDo(ProcessWords(), cutoff_length=2, marker='x')
             .with_outputs('above_cutoff_lengths', 'marked strings',
                           main='below_cutoff_strings')
             .with_output_types(str, IndexError, str)
)
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Why do you need to add the `with_outputs_types` in addition to `with_outputs` ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, actually, @MazlumTosun .  I want to have both normal type checks and runtime type checks, because our team is expanding and I want to ensure that we have some consistency and accuracy.  So I want to use `with_output_types` as a means to better establish clear, correct code. But maybe it actually will not catch anything in the runtime type checker, so that it isn't really helping??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I could be wrong, since you have not described the actual problem/error. Furthermore, the `DirectRunner` (which is used in the playground) completely ignores any typehints! In order to verify that this indeed solves your issue, this has to be executed in a runner which actually considers typehints (e.g., `Dataflow`).

Assuming the error you encounter is

> TypeError: PTransform.with_output_types() takes 2 positional arguments
> but 4 were given

If you look at the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.29.0/_modules/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.html#PTransform.with_output_types) of `with_output_types` then it only expects a single typehint. However, you are providing 3 individual ones. You need to wrap your typehints into a `Tuple`, e.g.

```
import apache_beam as beam
from typing import Tuple  # <- this is the important piece

class DoFnWithOutputs(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    if element == 1:
      yield "one"
    else:
      yield beam.pvalue.TaggedOutput("not_one", False)


with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
  input_data = pipeline | 'Create data' >> beam.Create([1, 2, 3, 1])

  being_one, not_being_one = (
    input_data
    | "DoFn" >> beam.ParDo(DoFnWithOutputs())
                .with_outputs("not_one", main="one")
                .with_output_types(Tuple[bool, str])   # Note the wrapping within 'Tuple'
  )
  
  (
    being_one
    | "print 1" >> beam.Map(print)
  )

  (
    not_being_one
    | "print != 1" >> beam.Map(print)
  )
```

which you can execute directly within the [Beam playground](https://play.beam.apache.org/?sdk=python&shared=pIbwknJTIWl).

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't actually have an error _yet_.  I just wasn't sure if I could do what you proposed.  I am in the process of trying it (using Dataflow).  If successful, I'll accept this. :)

Comment: This "worked", except that I think I ran across a bug within Beam itself: https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/30019